# AnyDac form design, programming query cancel dialog

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, anydac

I'm having a problem with my AnyDac Cancel dialog from TADGUIxAsyncExecuteDialog  component, basically i need the user to be able to cancel the query execution it works perfectly but the design doesn't match the program what i need is to edit the form that shows for the user to my needs, delete the icon of AnyDac change the caption etc.. any ideas how i can do this?

I'm using AnyDac 6.0.3 Build 2713 
Delphi XE

tried searching all over the internet for a week's now, no luck :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a workaround :)

```
    while AnyQuery.Command.State = csExecuting do
    begin
      Application.ProcessMessages;
      //do anything here while query is executing
      //the query has to be set to ResourceOptions.CmdExecMode = amAsync
      end;
    end;
```

Also you can cancel the query by executing the following command

```
AnyQuery.AbortJob(False);
```

My code looks like this:

```
AnyQuery.Active;
ShowProgressForm:= TShowProgressForm.Create(Application); 
ShowProgressForm.Label1.Caption := 'Generating Query Please Wait...';

while AnyQuery.Command.State = csExecuting do
begin
      Application.ProcessMessages;

      if ShowProgressForm.Cancel then
      begin
        AnyQuery.AbortJob(False);
        ShowProgressForm.Close;
        EXIT;
      end;
end;

ShowProgressForm.Close;
```

The `Cancel` is a global boolean variable declared in the `ShowProgressForm.pas` when you press the `Cancel` button the variable becomes `True` and the `AbortJob(False)` method will abort query execution :)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: No problem, i hope it helps others :)